# An exact sequence of unit groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, homological-algebra

In the [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/21715) of K. Conrad to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21709/what-are-the-advantages-of-phrasing-results-in-terms-of-exact-sequences-and-comm), he mentions a "nice 4-term short exact sequence of abelian groups (involving units groups mod a, mod b, and mod ab)" proving the product formula for $\phi$. How does this sequence look like? (I couldn't figure it out myself, the term $(a,b)$ in the formula puzzles me.) In a sense he only mentions the obvious about the sequence, that $U(a)$, $U(b)$ and $U(ab)$ should occur (which is not surprising since by definition $\phi(a):=\#U(a)$).

EDIT: Perhaps the sequence might be $$0\rightarrow \ker\rightarrow U(\mathbf{Z}/ab\mathbf{Z})\rightarrow U(\mathbf{Z}/a\mathbf{Z})\times U(\mathbf{Z}/b\mathbf{Z})\rightarrow \operatorname{Coker}\rightarrow 0$$

Comment: I'm guessing he is using (a,b) to denote gcd....but not positive. gotta run,but I will check in later if no progress has been made. One after thought, have you considered the exponent cancellation law?

Comment: @drawnonward: it is clear that $(a,b)$ denotes the gcd. what puzzles me is: what group contributes this term!

Answer (score 3):

As KCd mentions in the comments on his answer, the kernel and cokernel should be made more explicit. In your [follow-up question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827272/number-of-solutions-of-some-congruence-equations/827443#827443) I explicitly write down the elements in the kernel, and mention how the cokernel should be written as $U(\gcd(a,b))$, where the map is $(a,b)\mapsto ab^{-1}$. So we get

$$1\to K\to U(ab)\to U(a)\times U(b)\to U(\gcd(a,b))\to 1$$

as a short exact sequence (thanks to CRT). By the alternating product formula, we obtain

$$\frac{\gcd(a,b)\varphi(a)\varphi(b)}{\varphi(ab)\varphi(\gcd(a,b))}=1.$$

Comment: If you write down the kernel map (the kernel is apparently isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}/(a,b)\mathbf{Z}$) I will accept your answer

Comment: @Karl I am defining $K$ to be the kernel of $U(ab)\to U(a)\times U(b)$, so the map $K\to U(ab)$ is just the inclusion map. One doesn't need the structure of $K$, only its size, for this problem. (In fact I don't immediately see that it's cyclic.)

Comment: This is clear to me, but would be instructive to know, the sequence itself.

Comment: @Karl I don't understand your comment; the sequence is written plainly in my answer, and each map is understood. What's left to discuss?