# Number of solutions of some congruence equations.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, congruences

1. How many $[u]\in(\mathbf{Z}/ab\mathbf{Z})^\ast$ satisfy the equations $u\equiv 1 \bmod \ a$, $u\equiv 1 \bmod \ b$? I somehow believe that the answer might be $(a,b)$. Is this actually true?
2. Is the cardinality of the cokernel of the group homomorphism $(\mathbf{Z}/ab\mathbf{Z})^\ast\rightarrow(\mathbf{Z}/a\mathbf{Z})^\ast\times(\mathbf{Z}/b\mathbf{Z})^\ast$ equal to $\phi((a,b))$?

This would solve the related question [on the formula for $\phi$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827182/an-exact-sequence-of-unit-groups). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel of $U(ab)\to U(a)\times U(b)$ is comprised of the integer representatives

$$1+[a,b],~~1+2[a,b],~~1+3[a,b],~~\cdots,~~ 1+ab$$

the number of which is $ab/[a,b]=(a,b)$. (This fact can be argued elementarily via the usual "universal properties" argument ($d\mid a,b\Leftrightarrow a,b\mid ab/d\Leftrightarrow [a,b]\mid ab/d\Leftrightarrow d\mid ab/[a,b]$.)

There is a sequence $U(ab)\to U(a)\times U(b)\to U((a,b))$ where the latter homomorphism is given by $(x,y)\mapsto xy^{-1}$, which can be checked is exact by Chinese Remainder Theorem, so the cokernel does indeed have cardinality $\varphi((a,b))$.

But if the kernel of $U(ab)\to U(a)\times U(b)$ has $(a,b)$ elements, so the image has size $\varphi(ab)/(a,b)$, and so this is the size of the kernel of $U(a)\times U(b)\to U((a,b))$, and so the size of $U((a,b))$ is also given by $\varphi(a)\varphi(b)(a,b)/\varphi(ab)$, which rearranged yields the formula in KCd's original MO answer.

Comment: Second part: the OP wants *to prove* that formula (using an exact sequence), not *to use* it.

Comment: @user26857 I don't understand what you mean. I did prove it, no? In what way did I "use" it? Are you asking how to prove $\varphi(a)\varphi(b)\gcd(a,b)/\varphi(ab)$ equals $\varphi(\gcd(a,b))$? (Strange way to ask that...)

Comment: Ah, I think by the very mysterious phrase "that formula" you are referring to the product formula used implicitly to equate the two expressions. In order to figure this out I had to go to the link and see that OP is ultimately trying to prove the product formula. However, that purpose is not made clear within this question... I confess I don't immediately understand what four-term sequence and the resulting reasoning KCd is talking about.